# Angular ngx translate, TranslateService from global scope in static method

Tags: angular, class, static, ngx-translate

I would like to use the TranslateService(Angular ngx-translate) in my class in a static method.

```
export class ClassName {
    static CONFIG = {
        selectList: [
            { name: 'name', label: TranslateService.instant('my.i18n.key') }, // i need something like this
        ]
    }
```

OR something like this:

```
const translate = TranslateService reference from the root(global scope)

    export class ClassName {
    static CONFIG = {
        selectList: [
            { name: 'name', label: translate.instant('my.i18n.key') },
        ]
    }
```

How can i do this? Any idea?